# Why Luke uses ἀνήρ (man) for Mary (a woman)?

Tags: greek, luke

As I was studying the use of the Greek word ἀνήρ (anēr, [G435](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g435/nasb20/mgnt/0-1/)), I discovered surprisingly that Luke used this word for Mary in Luke 1:34.

Luke 1:34

> But Mary said to the angel, "How will this be, since I am a virgin[G435]?"

Can someone explain?

Comment: If you just follow your own link, you will find the actual Greek text and its word by word translation. Then you will see that literally the text says “I don’t know male” which means she’s a virgin. So your question is moot. https://www.blueletterbible.org/nasb20/luk/1/34/t_conc_974034

Comment: It is not used for a woman. The question is mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly to avoid offending anyone that thinks Mary would not talk that way, rather than literally translating her words, they used "I am a virgin" for the three Greek words:

- ἄνδρα — "husband" or "man" (noun, object)
- οὐ — "not" (adverb)
- γινώσκω —"I copulate" (verb)

The G435 word you were seeing in "*How be can this since husband not I copulate?*" is masculine because it means "husband".

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the Greek is simpler than it appears.  The last phrase is:

> ἐπεὶ ἄνδρα οὐ γινώσκω = "since a man/husband I know not"

That is, Mary is not saying she is a virgin, but only that she does not "know" (ie, does not sleep with) a man; that is, she does not live with a man and so is not sexually active and so cannot conceive.

That is, the word ἀνήρ (aner) does not refer to Mary but the husband that she does not have or know.